# Why is this function call in render() creating an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call a function in render() which will update the state. But when I do that, it gives me this error message:

`Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

I don't understand why this is happening because I'm not directly setting the state in my render(), I'm setting it in my setInsightUrl() function.

I've tried using different lifecycle functions but couldn't get any to work. I'm not sure how else to write this function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import "../../css/tabs/Tabs.css"
import {connect} from "react-redux"

class InsightPage extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            insightUrlState: null
        }

        this.setInsightUrl = this.setInsightUrl.bind(this);
    }

    setInsightUrl(url) {
        this.setState({
            insightUrlState: url
        })

        console.log(this.state.insightUrlState, 'INSIGHTTTTTT URLLLLLbgnhjm,k.l')
    }

    render() {
        this.props.sideTreeMenu.dynamicMenu.forEach(obj => {
            obj.children.forEach(child => {
                child.insights.forEach(insight => {
                    if (insight.insightName === this.props.insightNameReducer) {
                        {this.setInsightUrl(insight.insightURL)}
                    }
                })
            })
        })

        return (
            <div className={this.props.drawerOpen ? "tab_container2" : "tab_container" }>
                <h1>Hello from Insight</h1>
                <iframe frameBorder="0" style={{width: "100%", height: "70vh"}} src="https://insighttbdashboards.verizon.com/t/DigtalAnalytics/views/Digital_Analytics/Chat_Dashboard?iframeSizedToWindow=true&:embed=y&:showAppBanner=false&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no#2" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    drawerOpen: state.SideDrawerReducer.open,
    sideTreeMenu: state.SideDrawerReducer.menu,
    insightNameReducer: state.SideDrawerReducer.insightName
  })

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(InsightPage);
```

It should update the state with the url I am passing into the function in the render block.

Comment: Doesn't a call to `.setState()` trigger a render call?

Comment: @Pointy - yes, but I'm not sure how to get around it here. Any ideas?

Comment: *"I'm not directly setting the state in my render(), I'm setting it in my setInsightUrl() function"* -- yes you are, you've just moved the logic to a different function. By calling that function from `render()` you are effectively setting the state from the render function. But why are you determining the insightUrl there instead of in the constructor or in `getDerivedStateFromProps()`?

Comment: @rickdenhaan yup, could you write that as an answer please? ;)

Comment: @JonasWilms You're right, I was mostly curious why this logic was in `render()` instead of in a more logical place but I've added an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Just because you are calling `setState` in a function *defined* outside of render (`setInsightUrl`) doesn't mean you aren't calling it within `render`, `render` potentially calls `setInsightUrl` when the right conditions are met, and thus can potentially loop forever.

Perhaps you could update the state only if it actually is changing:

```js
setInsightUrl(url) {
  if (this.state.insightUrlState != url) {
    this.setState({
      insightUrlState: url
    })

    console.log(this.state.insightUrlState, 'INSIGHTTTTTT URLLLLLbgnhjm,k.l')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the code you posted (I'm not sure if that is the full code for your component) there's no need to determine the insight url in the `render()` function. If you do want to determine it in the render function (which should be the last thing your component does) then you shouldn't need to put it in the state, you should just use a local variable for it.

But if you want it in the state, you can either do it in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    let insightUrlState = null;
    props.sideTreeMenu.dynamicMenu.forEach(obj => {
        obj.children.forEach(child => {
            child.insights.forEach(insight => {
                if (insight.insightName === props.insightNameReducer) {
                    insightUrlState = insight.insightURL;
                }
            });
        });
    });

    this.state = { insightUrlState };
}
```

With an additional use of a lifecycle method if you want to update the state when the props change:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // depending on how many items are in these arrays, you might want to
    // wrap this in a check to see if this.props.sideTreeMenu.dynamicMenu has
    // changed from prevProps.sideTreeMenu.dynamicMenu and/or if
    // this.props.insightNameReducer has changed from prevProps.insightNameReducer
    let insightUrlState = null;
    this.props.sideTreeMenu.dynamicMenu.forEach(obj => {
        obj.children.forEach(child => {
            child.insights.forEach(insight => {
                if (insight.insightName === this.props.insightNameReducer) {
                    insightUrlState = insight.insightURL;
                }
            });
        });
    });

    if (prevState.insightUrlState !== insightUrlState) {
        this.setState({ insightUrlState });
    }
}
```

Or, alternatively, you can use the `getDerivedStateFromProps` function to determine the `insightUrlState` value *just* before rendering (using this function, you don't need to use the constructor or componentDidUpdate options):

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
    let insightUrlState = null;
    props.sideTreeMenu.dynamicMenu.forEach(obj => {
        obj.children.forEach(child => {
            child.insights.forEach(insight => {
                if (insight.insightName === props.insightNameReducer) {
                    insightUrlState = insight.insightURL;
                }
            });
        });
    });

    return { insightUrlState };
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I am still kind of confused. How do I use the insightUrlState variable and how do I update the state with that variable?

Answer (score -1):

```
this.props.sideTreeMenu.dynamicMenu.forEach(obj => {
  obj.children.forEach(child => {
     child.insights.forEach(insight => {
       if (insight.insightName === this.props.insightNameReducer) {
           {this.setInsightUrl(insight.insightURL)}
       }
     })
  })
})
```

This block is not valid JSX, you might need to move that to `componentDidMount`.

You can't call `setState` inside render, otherwise will cause a re-render, so it will go again to render and so on... That's why you got that error.

Comment: You can run arbitrary code in `render()`, and you can have JSX everywhere.

Comment: I don't think that work the way you expect it to work, you cannot have `{}` inside of a function that is not JSX. See in your code `{this.setInsightUrl(insight.insightURL)}`

Comment: @AlejandroGarciaAnglada Sure you can. `{}` outside of JSX context simply denotes a [code block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). It's perfectly valid javascript code and this will run without errors. Although in this particular case it's rather pointless.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to say. He is probably mixing concepts here. That is why I'm trying to remove those from the equation. Thank you for the clarification.